# How to transfer selected files from one pc to another in a fixed folder at a fixed time daily?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sir, I developed windows app in asp.net using C# which can transfer files which I select manually from one PC to another. But I want to transfer selected files daily without my any interaction to the application.. Could you suggest me how to do it?Should I generate Button_click event of file transfer using timer??

Comment: You developed a windows app in asp.net?

Comment: That is security-wise impossible with pure ASP.NET (HTML+JavaScript)!

Answer (score 1):

You should [schedule a windows task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task) to execute your application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to transfer the files from one computer to other, You cannot do so using asp.net. Instead you will need to develop window application or service which will reside on the computer from where you need to copy the file.(It can reside on other comp also.)
if both the computer are on the same network then simply use file copy method.

Comment: No I have developed this tool as windows application using C# language in .net framework. Instead of sending a single file using openFileDialog I want to send a complete folder from one pc to another..How to do this please get me some idea..